# Convergence proof for perceptron algorithm with margin

Tags: classification, neural-networks

I was looking for the proof of convergence for [perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) algorithm with margin. I was not able to find it in any pattern classification text book or over the internet.

Can anyone here please point to a text or reference for the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the answer depends upon exactly which algorithm you have in mind. I would take a look in Brian Ripley's 1996 book, Pattern Recognition and Neural Networks, page 116. Here is a (very simple) proof of the convergence of Rosenblatt's *perceptron learning algorithm* if that is the algorithm you have in mind. This is replicated as Exercise 4.6 in Elements of Statistical Learning.

The algorithm presented on the Wikipedia page looks a little different from the algorithm in Ripley's book, but from what I can tell they are up to some initial normalizations doing the same.

Please note that convergence means that for a linearly separable data set the algorithm reach a fixed point after a finite number of iterations, but the value of the fixed point depends upon the start value for the algorithm.